# will synchronized lock wait till the completion of another thread in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am confused if the below code will wait or skip execution of the block,

```
synchronized(lock)
{
  //Do something...
  //...
  //...
  //...
}
```

And is it possible to use boolean values as parameter for synchronized? And what are mutex locks?
If it is not going to wait, is its only purpose is to make a code statement thread safe and only for critical section based access?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should look at gcd (Grand Central Dispatch). It really helps with all aspects of threaded code.

Answer (score 3):

@synchronized will wait until the lock is available. It declares a critical section around the code block. In multithreaded code, @synchronized guarantees that only one thread can be executing that code in the block at any given time.

Comment: So after the lock is released, it will execute the block? Is there any way to use boolean instead of Nslock variable?

Comment: Yes. It will wait until it can acquire / lock and execute that critical section

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "use boolean"

Comment: Wait until the Bool value has changed to true. Is that possible in synchronized?

Comment: Use NSConditionLock or GCD.

Comment: If you are using `@synchronized() { }`, you don't need an `NSLock`.  While they _can_ be used together, they are typically mutually-exclusive: you use one or the other.  The typical object passed to `@synchronized() { }` is `self`.